# fopen code working on windows but not on ubundu

Tags: php, html, windows, ubuntu

I have the following php code which is working correctly on windows but not in Ubuntu 12.04 ,

```
<?php
$date="hi";
$filename="files/".$date.".txt";
echo $filename;
$fop=fopen($filename,"a");
echo $fop;
fclose($fop);
?>
```

Please help me to resolve my issue. Thanks

Comment: _It's not working_ - succinct, accurate and totally useless. Perhaps you'd describe what this is supposed to do, and how it fails.

Comment: `files/hi.txt` is a relative file path and depends on the working directory of the server process satisfying your request.  Perhaps an absolute path could be more reliable as it would not require you to know the location of the working directory ? Also check existence and permissions.

Comment: @Paul I have find out the reason, it is because of  the php user doesn't have the permission.

Answer (score 0):

***Check your files permissions with chmod***

```
if( chmod("yourFileName", 0775) ){
    // your code here
}
```

***and in linux this file is absolute, ex:***

```
/var/www/html/folder/file.txt
```